Encountering ValueError with numpy While Installing schemachange in Python
Receiving this issue when I'm trying to install schemachange in pyhton

ValueError: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96 from C header, got 88 from PyObject

This was working for months.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bnumpy%5d%20ValueError%3a%20numpy.dtype%20size%20changed%2c%20may%20indicate%20binary%20incompatibility.%20Expected%2096%20from%20C%20header%2c%20got%2088%20from%20PyObject&searchOn=3

Not yet compatible with NumPy 2.0.

I had the same issue. Try to downgrade numpy==1.26.4 solved my issue.
This is a bug on the numpy side. The issue is still open. https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/26710
